# How does Hyperledger Fabric implement private data sharing among related parties?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, corda

How does Hyperledger Fabric share the private data only among intended parties without revealing the data to the other network participants?

Is it similar to R3's Corda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of fabric v0.6 does not provide such possibility, i.e. every peer can see the same as the other peers. But there is intention to implement this feature in 1.0 http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abstract_v1/

Comment: Is this the document you are talking about?
https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/wiki/Next-Consensus-Architecture-Proposal#6-confidentiality

Answer (score 2):

As of Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.0, full support for `channels` is provided. A channel can be thought of as an overlay network in a larger blockchain network, including a restricted set of peers belonging to selected organizations and an orderer. All transactions are conducted in the context of a `channel`, and all transaction information is shared ONLY with those peers that participate in the channel.

More information can be found in the [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fabric_model.html#privacy-through-channels).

Answer (score 2):

In Fabric version 1.2, support for 'private data collections' was added, in addition to the concept of 'channels'.  Private data collections allow for organizations on a (blockchain) channel to share private data peer-to-peer, with a hash of the private data going on the blockchain. See more details in the [private data documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html).

For a comparison with Corda, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204731/8205919).